# Average of values between current row and min date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a table with two columns date & value. the table is always sorted by date is descending order.

Now i need the average of values against between the current row date and minimum date.

e.g

Date        Value        Avg
31-Jan     2000        2400
30-Jan     4000        2500
29-Jan     3000        2000
28-Jan     1000        1500
27-Jan     2000        2000

the average range for values should be between the row date and minimum date e.g. for 28th jan it should calculate values only for 28th & 27th and for 30th it should calculate values only from 30th Jan to 27th Jan.

Can anyone help with a mysql code. i am completely clueless about it.

Comment: @JohnRuddell He wants the average based on the given date `x` and every other date `<= x`. For example Jan 29th, `3000+1000+2000/3 = 2000`

Comment: Tables are not sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9b2e/33/0)):

```
SELECT m.Date, m.Value, AVG(m2.Value) AS Avg
FROM MyTable m
LEFT JOIN MyTable m2 ON m.Date >= m2.Date
GROUP BY m.Date
ORDER BY m.Date DESC
```

If your `Date` field is of **Date** or **Datetime** type then the above query will work.  However, if your `Date` field is a string, then you will not get the results you are after.

If your `Date` field is a string and already sorted in descending order, then you could use the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac0aa/1/0)):

```
SELECT m.Date, m.Value, AVG(m2.sValue) AS Avg
FROM
(
  SELECT s.Date, s.Value, @i:=@i+1 AS rn
  FROM MyTable s
  ,(SELECT @i:=0) AS foo
) m
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT s.Date AS sDate, s.Value AS sValue, @j:=@j+1 AS srn
  FROM MyTable s
  ,(SELECT @j:=0) AS foo
) m2 ON m.rn <= m2.srn
GROUP BY m.Date
ORDER BY m.Date DESC;
```

Comment: Why so complicated when `SELECT AVG(value) FROM TABLE WHERE date <= X` would do? The only issue I see here is that storing date format as `d-m` wouldn't work once you start having different years.

Comment: **@Aziz Saleh**, I changed my answer to something a little more sophisticated.

Comment: The 1st query is fine if `Date` in unique. The 2nd is not guaranteed to work. It will give indeterminate results.